# Is it a good idea to make header and adapt it to the mobile screens right away?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wanted to ask is it a good idea to create header and after that adapt it to the mobile screens, even though other parts of the website are not created?

Comment: Doesn't really matter, though I would suggest creating all the content, then adding stuff like responsiveness.

Comment: @sean-7777 - So you're suggesting the opposite of [mobile-first design](https://xd.adobe.com/ideas/process/ui-design/what-is-mobile-first-design/)? Bold. ;-D

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I like to do it that way, and it works for me.

Comment: Fair enough. :-)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good idea. I know for sure it's not a good idea to ask for opinions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a mobile-first approach. If your application is gonna be responsive in the future then start by designing with mobile CSS. Then incrementally increase the dimension and add the media queries based on that.